# Emacs switches to old buffers when a stale command is quit

Tags: emacs

I must be in the habit of leaving the mini-buffer in the middle of a command.  From there I will change buffers and continue working.  Later (sometimes much later) I'll notice that I had a command dangling incomplete in the mini-buffer.  If I go to cancel it with a <kbd>C-g</kbd>, Emacs will often swap buffers in my open windows to an earlier state.

I suppose this may be a feature, but in my flow of work I find it rather annoying.  Is there a way to stop this behavior or prevent it from happening, such as a warning that There is an incomplete command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022880/how-can-i-prevent-the-mini-buffer-from-displaying-previous-commands-in-emacs) will help you solve this.  It can be an annoying behavior, but the solution limits some of the flexibility found in Emacs.

The answer is: [How can I prevent the mini-buffer from displaying previous commands in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022880/how-can-i-prevent-the-mini-buffer-from-displaying-previous-commands-in-emacs/3024055#3024055) (I call it [`stop-using-minibuffer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022880/how-can-i-prevent-the-mini-buffer-from-displaying-previous-commands-in-emacs/3024055#3024055)).